# Desktop unresponsive after switching from text TTY on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: xorg, 19.04, tty

Whenever I switch virtual terminals from a text mode `tty` to the graphical desktop on Ubuntu 19.04 the desktop is unresponsive for 5 to 10 seconds.

When in graphics mode I can move the mouse, but nothing else responds. When the desktop finally "wakes" up it executes the keypresses that have been buffered. If I immediately switch back to another text mode `tty`s they work just fine. It's just the graphical desktop that takes a timeout.

What can I do to fix this?